# Copy IPv4-address from byte array to string

Tags: c#, arrays, ip-address

I have an ipv4-address stored in a byte array.  At index `n` and until index `n+3` each index takes 4 bytes.

```
(index)              n       n+1     n+2    n+3                 
[..] [..] [..] [ 1st byte ][ 2nd ] [ 3rd ] [ 4th ] [..] [..]
```

how to copy this construction to string. I want to receive string like "192.168.0.1", while

```
byteArray[n] =   192;
byteArray[n+1] = 168;
byteArray[n+2] = 0;
byteArray[n+3] = 1;
```

**Finally, the problem was solved and the solution is:**

```
string str = recCommand.parameters[10] + "." + recCommand.parameters[11] +
 "." +   recCommand.parameters[12] + "." + recCommand.parameters[13];
```

Comment: so what is stored in tbe Byte[] array before your first octet? If its null, then you can simply look through the array checking if !null and storing the results in a string....    loop byte[] array..check !null ... += string.        sorry for the crudeness of the post.

Comment: there is part of query command received via TCP, and it is not a null

Comment: @vard - What have you tried exactly? Just convert the index `n` through `n + 3` to a string and combine them.  Until you actually show what you have tried I have to down vote this question.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, that's I've tried. Here is the piece of real code:
`string str = recCommand.parameters[10] + "." + recCommand.parameters[11] + "." + recCommand.parameters[12] + "." + recCommand.parameters[13];`

Comment: @vard - You need to update the question with what you have attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this

```
        byte[] some = { 192, 168, 0, 1 };
        String ip = "" + some[0] + "." + some[1] + "." + some[2] + "." + some[3];
        Console.WriteLine("ip=" + ip  );
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks, there was a comment by Anne with same advice, but unfortunately author deleted it. It works, great, thanks.

Comment: could be simplified to string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", some)